# How can I declare HashMap<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>?

Tags: java, hashmap

I declare hashmap; String as key and ArrayList of ArrayList of String as value.

```
public Map<String,ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> idPathMap = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>();
```

But it show the error:The type HashMap is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments `<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>`

How can I declare this type of HashMap?

Comment: What `HashMap` are you importing?  It seems to work okay for me (Java 8)

Comment: `Map<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> idPathMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>();` doesn't give any error in Java 8

Comment: Check your imports, maybe u are using the old one..

Comment: import is java.util.Map

Comment: @YuWaiHlaing It works fine........no error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it show the error:The type HashMap is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments >>

You have created your own class named `HashMap`. Rename your class (it [masks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_resolution_%28programming_languages%29#Name_masking) `java.util.HashMap`, even if you have imported it). **Or**,

```
public Map<String,ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> idPathMap = 
    new java.util.HashMap<String,ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>();
```

**or** on Java 8+

```
public Map<String,ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> idPathMap = 
    new java.util.HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I didn't notice about my own class HashMap. It works now.